# I want to know the meaning in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, paraphrasing

Opportunity is missed by most people and it is dressed in overalls and looks like work.

—By T Edison

What is the meaning of "dress","overall"here & the phrase "looks like work", is here wok is a verb??i want a paraphrase..

Comment: When you 'dress in overalls', you put them on to protect your clothes when you are doing   manual work.

Comment: ... **because** it is dressed ...

Comment: Looks an awful lot like the sentiment better expressed by golfer Gary Player as ***The more I practice the luckier I get***. But of course, to a professional golfer, "practice" ***is*** "work", so Google now finds tens of thousands of instances of *The **harder** I **work** the luckier I get*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - 'fortune favours the prepared', my father used to say.

Answer (score 1):

"dressed in X" means simply "wearing X". Overalls are clothes that manual workers wear. (easy to check that in a dictionary)

> Katie was dressed in a blouse and skirt.

"work" is a noun.  The phrase "X looks like Y" means "X appears to be Y" or "X is similar to Y".

The expression is figurative "Opportunity" is personified as being "dressed in overalls" (like a manual worker, not an office worker) and appearing to be work. People miss opportunities because they don't recognise the fact that to make the most of opportunities you have to work for it. That is, if you want opportunities you have to do lots of manual work.

Comment: What is the meaning of the noun "work" here—?

Comment: The usual meaning of work, from the dictionary "activity (such as a job) involving mental or physical effort, done in order to achieve a purpose or result."   Please look up the meaning of words in the dictionary first.

Comment: @JamesK, maybe a dictionary is an opportunity that looks like work

Comment: @JamesK I can say "we miss opportunity bcoz it seems difficult to achieve and require hard work."

Comment: @Sam - 'bcoz' -No! No! No! **Because**. Also **requires**.